# How to jump to #+RESULTS: when point is at Org source block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, navigation

When `point` is on a source block, I want to be able to jump to the `#+RESULTS` section of that source block. If the source block does not have a `#+RESULTS:` section, I want to do nothing: I don't want to jump to any `#+RESULTS:` below, not belonging to the source block I'm on.

Is there a function that does that already? If not, how do I write such a function?

Comment: Can you better explain your question? Your question says 'how to jump to results' and your 'explanation' says 'do not jump to results'.

Comment: The body of the question should contain the question! You should include the question in the body even if you have to repeat what you wrote in the title. See if my edit reflects what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c c") (lambda () (interactive) 
  (goto-char 
  (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE.  Self-answers are fine and even encouraged, but the one you posted is basically a less robust version of the one posted yesterday.  Let me suggest you delete this post and accept the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I have interpreted your question correctly (see the edited question), there is no built-in function to *go* to the result block, but there is a utility function, `org-babel-where-is-src-block-result`, that tells *where* the result block is (it returns `nil` if there is no result block). So it's easy to put together a function that goes to the results block (if present):

```el
(defun my/org-babel-goto-result ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((location (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result)))
    (when location
      (goto-char location)))
```

Now do `M-x my/org-babel-goto-result` when on a source block. It moves `point` to the result (if present); it does nothing if there is no result present. And it does nothing if you call it from somewhere other than a source block.

You can bind the function to a key if you want:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'my/org-babel-goto-result)

;; or in recent Emacsen (29.1 and later), you can use the following instead
(keymap-set org-mode-map "C-c z" #'my/org-babel-goto-result)
```